# UITableView dark theme

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I'm trying to make my app use a dark theme, so far I've changed the style of navigation controllers and tab bar controller to *Dark* from the storyboard to get the system dark theme but when I tried to make my table views dark I wasn't able to find an equivalent option.

Am I missing something and there is an option, in storyboard or code, to make all `UITableView`s use a system dark theme? If not, what is the best way to achieve this using default/standard colours?

I'm trying to achieve something similar to the Activity app that becomes available when you pair an Apple Watch:
[image]

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of "dark theme"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "dark theme"... unless you create one yourself.

There are various ways that you can customise a `UITableView` though...

The best place to find them is [the Apple Documentation for UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview#).

You can change the `backgroundColor` the cell colour the separator colour, etc, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I achieved my goal via UIAppearance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no implementation out of the box by Apple.

Here's a universal approach:

1. Make a `Theme` class for UI configuration. It will hold several properties like UIColors/UIImages/SystemSoundIDs/Strings etc. depending on what you need.
2. You could also make a `config json file` and make a theme parameters list for theme configuration. (this will make it easier to configure if you want to change smth fast or even receive a json config from server for example and configure the whole app)
3. `Theme` object will take certain parameters or fields of a json file and configure fonts/colors/backgrounds/sizes etc.
4. You can make a method, something like `class func applyThemeToViewController(vc: UIViewController, theme: Theme)` for configuring a certain screen or config something global through `UIAppearence` proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I don't plan to support multiple themes, configuring globally via UIAppearence in the app delegate is enough

Comment: @MarcoBoschi if you are sure you won't scale the functionality of your theming - yes, but I would recommend to make a separate Theme class for configuring target screens. It will not take a lot of time but the implementation will be more flexible and readable ;)